# ORDER_BY with collation in SAP HANA

Tags: sql-order-by, hana, collation

In my table I've got values with polish diacritics signs. I want to query it and sort the result with the right order. I need collation to do this, but I don't know how to use it in SAP HANA database.

**Test table**

```
CREATE COLUMN TABLE TEST_ORDER_BY (
    ID BIGINT null,
    PL_VALUE VARCHAR (20) null,
    DE_VALUE VARCHAR (20) null 
);

INSERT INTO TEST_ORDER_BY VALUES(1,'Aaa','Straße');
INSERT INTO TEST_ORDER_BY VALUES(2,'aaa','Strasse');
INSERT INTO TEST_ORDER_BY VALUES(3,'Bbbb','Strase');
INSERT INTO TEST_ORDER_BY VALUES(4,'bbbb','Strasze');
INSERT INTO TEST_ORDER_BY VALUES(5,'Ąaa','Aaa');
INSERT INTO TEST_ORDER_BY VALUES(6,'ąaa','ßStrae');
INSERT INTO TEST_ORDER_BY VALUES(7,'zz','Zzzz');
INSERT INTO TEST_ORDER_BY VALUES(8,'zaąa','aaa');
INSERT INTO TEST_ORDER_BY VALUES(9,'zaąz','bbb');
INSERT INTO TEST_ORDER_BY VALUES(10,'zabz','Strasße');
```

**SQL Query**

```
SELECT id, pl_value
FROM TEST_ORDER_BY
ORDER BY pl_value ASC;
```

**Result**

```
ID  PL_VALUE
1   Aaa
3   Bbbb
2   aaa
4   bbbb
10  zabz
8   zaąa
9   zaąz
7   zz
5   Ąaa
6   ąaa
```

**Expected result**

```
        ID PL_VALUE            
---------- --------------------
         1 Aaa                 
         2 aaa                 
         5 Ąaa                 
         6 ąaa                 
         3 Bbbb                
         4 bbbb                
         8 zaąa                
         9 zaąz                
        10 zabz                
         7 zz
```

What I need is `a` to be followed by `ą` and same for other diacritics signs like `ęóśłżźń`.
I found the view `M_COLLATIONS` in the database (without polish collation) and column `COLLATION` in `TABLE_COLUMNS` view, but I don't know how to set it for speciefied column.

What can I do?

Comment: Do you know if there was ever a collate function introduced?

Comment: @cgage1 check this https://answers.sap.com/questions/606548/orderby-with-collation-in-sap-hana.html

Answer (score 3):

Even though the system view is there collations are not supported with HANA so far.(2.03.33)
I assume this view is going to be used with a feature in later HANA version.

Comment: Just an update: as you noticed [there](https://answers.sap.com/comments/12633338/view.html), and as NineBerry said in a separate answer, `ORDER BY ... COLLATE ...` is supported since HANA 2.0 SPS04.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with SPS04, specifying collations in an order by clause is supported:

An example would be:

```
select * from mytable order by col1 COLLATE TURKISH;
```

https://answers.sap.com/answers/12900664/view.html

Comment: More information about COLLATE: [SAP note 2448829 - Wrong sorting sequence of special Danish characters "æøå" in HANA](https://me.sap.com/notes/0002448829), [SELECT ... ORDER BY ... COLLATE ...](https://help.sap.com/docs/search?q=SELECT%20Statement%20%28Data%20Manipulation%29&locale=en-US&product=SAP_HANA_PLATFORM), [COLLATIONS System View](https://help.sap.com/docs/search?q=COLLATIONS%20System%20View&locale=en-US&product=SAP_HANA_PLATFORM)